# Unable to fetch component data using Graphql in Strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am building Graphql api with Strapi. It's a simple application which user can signup and save some of his/her information. I have two tables for that, User [Which is Strapi provided] and Profile which i use to store user additional information. The two tables has relationship

**User** `[User has and belongs to one Profile]`

[image]

**Profile** `Profile has and belongs to one User` and contact component structure.

[image]

I want to be able to fetch the current logged in user and it's information from Profile table, but the Contact field which i save as component type return null.

Here is what i am doing so far

**extensions/user-permission/config/schema.graphql.js**

```
module.exports = {
  definition: `
    extend type UsersPermissionsMe {
      profile: ProfileMe
    }

    type ProfileMe {
      id: ID!
      website: String!
      description: String!
      contact: ContactMe
    }

    type ContactMe {
      id: ID!
      name: String!
      phone: String!
      email: String!
    }

  `
}
```

**extensions/user-permission/services/User.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  fetchAuthenticatedUser(id) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').findOne({ id }, ['role', 'profile']);
  },
};
```

***And when run GraphQl Query***

```
query {
  me {
    username
    email
    profile {
      website
      description
      contact {
        name
        phone
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**it returned**

```
{
  "data": {
    "me": {
      "username": "company",
      "email": "company@test.com",
      "profile": {
        "website": "http://localhost.com",
        "description": "lorem text",
        "contact": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to also get contact data here. I hope someone on Internet can help me.
please help, thanks you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also facing the same problem.